# O que é Workspace no Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, workspace

O que é um **Workspace** no Visual Studio Code e qual a diferença entre trabalhar com **Estrutura de Pastas** e trabalhar com Workspace?

[image: Workspace Visual Studio Code]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Workspace não é apenas um Folder que você pega e arrasta para o VS Code. No WS (WorkSpace) você vai pode fazer inúmeras configurações, além de gerenciar `path` dos arquivos etc.

***Update 04/02/21***: Artigo mais recente sobre Workspace na documentação oficial do próprio VS Code https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces

Imagina que abriu um folder no VSCode, depois disso tem que salvar esse folder como um WS. Após você pode por exemplo:

- Trocar o Tema de cores
- Trocar atalhos de Teclado
- Habilitar ou desabilitar extensões
- Adicionar pastas nesse Folder, mas que na verdade estão em outro `path`

Todas essas mudanças ficam salvas no seu WS e fica configurado assim, sempre que abri-lo ele virá com essas configs.

Se quiser por exemplo um tema diferente para um WS em particular, pode colocar no arquivo de config o código abaixo. *(tem que escolher o tema antes de salvar o WS)*

```
"settings": {
      // Specifies the color theme used in the workbench.
      "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+"
}
```

Dois fatores interessantes extras é possível dar um Find in Folders apenas dentro do que está no WS. E mais interessante ainda esse arquivo que salvou do seu WS pode ser compartilhado, sim, isso mesmo, você pode configurar todo um WS e compartilhar o arquivo com seu time.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: Aqui está a documentação oficial do VS Code sobre o WorkSpace https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Answer (score 3):

O `workspace` é basicamente um projeto com uma ou mais pastas raiz onde você pode guardar tudo relacionado ao projeto (configurações, extensões, etc). 
Esta opção `Save Workspace As...` irá gerar um arquivo `.code-workspace` com algumas configurações padrões. É possível você editar as configurações do arquivo como desejar. Para mais obter mais informações sobre as configurações do workspace e outros, basta dar uma olhada na [documentação do Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs).

Caso você tenha fechado o seu `workspace`, você pode simplesmente clicar na opção `Open Workspace...` e selecionar o arquivo `.code-workspace` criado. Dessa forma você irá abrir novamente o `workspace` do seu projeto.

Answer (score -3):

Como eu uso bastante o NetBeans para front-end, entendi o Workspaces como um recurso igual à aba Projects, onde posso trabalhar com vários projetos abertos e alternar entre eles.
No caso do VsCode, com boas possibilidades de personalização.